# "zsh: command not found: meteor" on Windows 10

Tags: windows, meteor, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed Meteor on Windows 10 and here's what I get when I run `meteor -v` in the Hyper terminal (under zsh) : `zsh: command not found: meteor`.

When I run the same command in CMD.exe, the result is different :

```
run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

To create a new Meteor project:
  meteor create <project name>
For example:
  meteor create myapp

For more help, see 'meteor --help'.
```

The PATH in Windows is the following : `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\.meteor`. Could you tell me why it doesn't work under Zsh? Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Try running `which meteor` in `zsh`; 2. command should be `meteor --version`

Comment: No, it still doesn't work, the same message `zsh: command not found: meteor` is displayed.

I tried to install it with `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` but once it reaches 100% of downloading, nothing happens and Meteor won't install.

Any idea?

EDIT: I waited longer and it finally installed :)